# Set Content Search Webpart to 1st result page

Tags: 2013, cswp

I'm using `IssueQuery()` in my JS to refresh the results of my CSWP. The problem here is that if I chose second page and then use the same method, the results are not displayed on first page and are rather still pointing to 2nd page. In short the control template is not resetting to show 1st page every time result set is changed.

How can I achieve it through JS?

Note: I've more than one CSWP on my page, so I want to do it through CSWP `ctrl`

Answer (score 0):

You can call below code after `IssueQuery()`

```
document.getElementById('PageLink_1').click()
```

Comment: I've more than one CSWP on my page

Comment: also this code returns null :/

Comment: If you are getting the `ctrl` from $getClientControl, then please try: `ctrl.page(1);`

Comment: Whenever I do this, ctrl is empty. i.e. if I add this line my ctrl becomes null. it works perfectly via console though. Real Strange!

Comment: Could you try adding below line to display template
`AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function() { ctx.DataProvider.page(1); });`

Comment: Will this not always default it back to page 1 even if user do a paging? I'm not sure but will give it a try.